# when you read a sentence that starts off "For since in the wisdom", what is the writer stating. For and since is not usally used together like this

Tags: phrase-meaning

As I read I have come across the sentence above and am not sure what the writer is referring to or what he is stating.

Comment: Without any context, how can anyone know?

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22For+since+in+the+wisdom%E2%80%9D) the context (from 1812 or earlier): *For since, in the wisdom of God, the world by wisdom knew not God, God was pleased by the foolishness of preaching to save those that believe...*. But frankly, if that means anything at all, it passes me by. I'd say it's a bad translation (of *Corinthians* in the Christian Bible New Testament) as well as being hopelessly antiquated. It certainly won't teach you anything about *current* English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The translation is weak because, in order to be is literal as possible, it is trying to make the prepositions do too much work. We are supposed to understand "by X" to mean "using X as a tool".

Comment: @David42: Well, ELL isn't running a Bible Study class here. I've no doubt that the text does embody some "meaningful meaning" (though that'll be precious little to me as a committed atheist). But it's hardly useful stuff for anyone wanting to actually learn English today.

Comment: In future you should post a complete sentence and highlight the part you are having trouble with. If you do not understand the sentence, you do not know how to pull out a complete expression. Here the complete expression is "the wisdom of God".

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why I didn't get into the context or Paul's views. As a question about the English used in a famous work (the King James Bible) I consider it on-topic.

Comment: @David42:  It might be On Topic on ELU, as a question about antiquated writing styles, but obviously I don't think it's relevant *here*, as an aid to people wanting to learn *current* English (and I don't think "learners" should normally concern themselves with aspects of English that are no longer applicable). Whatever - I seriously doubt you could convince me to change my mind, but if you have sufficient rep, you can always vote to reopen it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not advocating re-opening it. Whether the phrase "in the wisdom of [someone]" is on-topic for ELL or not, the question as written is defective.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I have the context (thanks @FumbleFingers), I see where the confusion is coming from. Let's break it down. For reference, the whole context is [1st Corinthians 20-25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%201&version=ESV).

**For since, in the wisdom of God...**

This means "Because, in the wiseness of God's thinking (i.e. wisdom)"

**...the world by (its) wisdom knew not God...**
This means, "The world did not know (discover and understand) salvation through inborn, natural human thinking (i.e. logic, reasoning)..."

**...God was pleased by the foolishness of preaching to save those that believe.**
...that because of both of these things, God was pleased by the foolishness (i.e. foolishness according to man) of preaching, as a means to bring salvation to men.

Paul is saying that humankind tries to reason or figure out God, and so, to frustrate this, God made the knowledge of salvation not discoverable that way. Instead, he used something that humankind naturally thinks is foolish (preaching) to communicate His salvation. This is to demonstrate that God's wisdom is greater than man's wisdom.

Reading the verses around it (linked above) helps a lot, esp. 1 Cor 25:

"For the foolishness of God is wiser than men, and the weakness of God is stronger than men."

Paul goes even further -- not only is the wisdom of God wiser than the wisdom of men, even what men call foolishness of God is wiser than the wisdom of men.

Answer (score 0):

I'd venture to say it is not a common use nowadays.

The only reference I found for this sentence is in the Bible *1 Corinthians 1:21*:

> For since in the wisdom of God the world through its wisdom did not know him, God was pleased through the foolishness of what was preached to save those who believe.

The way I understand it would be something like:

> Because God chose for people not to be able to know him, he will save people who have enough faith to believe in his existence without proof.